# Can someone help me understanding the working of 3-stage comparator/ discriminator, shown in attachment?

Tags: power-electronics, comparator

I am working on a project and I need a high DC gain comparator for it.

M1,M2 are tge main differential amplifier and M1a, M2a are used for hysteresis.

As per my understanding its a 3 stage comparator: differential amplifier, common source amplifier and inverter.

But I can't understand the connection of main differential PMOD pair, encircled in red circle as current loads.

Can somebody kindly explain it?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please be specific i.e. what does "Main differential Pmos pair as current loads" actually mean? If you were using double asterisks to make your words bold, no need.

Comment: @Andyaka -  This is actually a 3 stage discriminator/Comparator. I have added one more picture, encircling the part i want to understand. 
I will like if anyone understands this circuit can tell, how it works actually.

Comment: Differential bipolar cascode with current sinks and mirrored current sources with voltage negative feedback on opposite polarity

Comment: But negative feedback using a inverter on the left positive input side causes hysteresis. For peak and hold detection...on each side thus pp discriminator

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you for your reply. I hope that's the right answer.

I have added a new picture numbering all mosfets. Can you kindly explain it in following points:

=> M9 and M11 is common source amplifier right?
=> M13 and M15 makes an inverter?
=> What is use of M5 and M7? 
=> M3 is used as current mirror . Should not it be used as a ressistive load here and baised byy some external Bias?

Comment: I1 Current sink is mirrored  fromM3 to M5,M9  down  M11, mirrored to M8 and M7 mirrored  to M12until other polarity OutA is active then shunted by M2a.   And same for right side. Gm and Vt are all critical and matched for Vgs vs Rds. It cannot be done by discrete part tolerances